# Firefox: change default application

Tags: gnome, firefox, mime-type, file-association

Me default djvu viewer is okular:

- `xdg-mime`:

  ```
  $ xdg-mime query default image/vnd.djvu
  okular.desktop
  ```
- in `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

  ```
  [Added Associations]
  image/vnd.djvu=okular.desktop;evince.desktop;
  ```
- When I click on a djvu -- okular opens it.
- in `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` (`/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` links to this file):

  ```
  image/vnd.djvu=okular.desktop
  ```

However firefox thinks my default app for djvus is evince:

[image]

How do I set okular as a default viewer in firefox? [this doesn't mean I want "Use okular" to be a default action -- I just want it to be a default viewer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I solved it:

```
xdg-mime default okular.desktop image/vnd.djvu
```

I wonder where this information is stored, since I already had it in my local `mimeapps.list`.

---

So in order to set a default program for sime filetype, one has to find it's mime type first -- which can be done by looking at `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` for example (and at `/etc/mime.types` in case no part of the mime-type is obvious, but You know the extension), and then find out wither there's a `.desktop` file for an application desired. Folders to be searched are:

- `/usr/share/applications` and
- `$HOME/.local/share/applications`

and then call `xdg-mime`.